# Cant get menu in div that is being pulled down on click back on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to create is a menu that comes down from the top of the page with Jquery.
This all works out fine with the following code.

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menucontentwrapper">
        <div id="menucontent"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menutabwrapper">
        <div id="menutab">MENU</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#menutab').click(function() {
$('#menu').animate({
top: '+=200',
}, 1000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
})
</script>
```

So on click of the 'menutab' div the whole thing comes down to the location where I want it, but I want it to go back up when people click the 'menutab' again and what ever I try it doesn't seem to work.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ be a viable option?

Comment: Maybe when I look at it, I just have no clue how to put that in..

Comment: you could chain a mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ event in your click event after the animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#menutab').click(function() {
    $('#menutab').hide();
    $('#menu').animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
});


$('#menu').mouseleave(function () {
    if($(this).css("top")=='0px') {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '-200px'
        }, 1000, function() {
            $('#menutab').show();
        });
    }
});
```